# java thread pool behaves differently when running the same task multiple times？

Tags: java, timeout, task, threadpool, future

I used Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8) to execute some time consuming tasks,and used future.get method to set timeout with 10 seconds.Then I found that some tasks could be executed successfully when they were executed alone, but timeout when they executed with any other tasks.These tasks are independent of each other, cpu and memory was sufficient.Why would it happen?

Comment: Show us your code,please

Comment: It will be hard to answer without profiling. One possible problem is that your tasks compete over system bus or cache.

Answer (score 0):

I already know the reason.it's due to the difference of wall time and thread time.future.get set the wall time of thread,but due to CPU time slice rotation,the real running time of thread is thread time.When tasks executed concurrently,even small tasks risk starvation.